# get url from Jersey WriterInterceptor

Tags: java, rest, jersey, interceptor

I know there is a way to get the URL in the ContainerRequestFilter class of Jersey.

is there a way to get the URL from writerInterceptor inside the aroundWriteTo method?

```
@Provider
public class RequestClientWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) 
  throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    context.getOutputStream()
      .write(("Message added in the writer interceptor in the client side").getBytes());

    context.proceed();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just inject [`UriInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html) into the interceptor. You can get all the URI related goodies you need from this object.

```
@Provider
public class RequestClientWriterInterceptor implements WriterInterceptor {

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;
}
```

You don't have to worry about any race conditions or anything of that sort as a threadlocal proxy will be injected, not the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

You can send URL also in a new header name and then use [getHeaders](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/WriterInterceptorContext.html#getHeaders--) to get specific header:

```
 MultivaluedMap<String,Object> headers = context.getHeaders();
```

Comment: does the headers include the full url of the original request?

Answer (score 0):

I got the URL by retrieving the HttpChannel from the context properties and then getting the Request off the HttpChannel.  See the following....

```
@Override
public void aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorContext context) 
  throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

    HttpChannel httpChannel = (HttpChannel) context.getProperty(HttpChannel.class.getName());
    String url = httpChannel.getRequest().getOriginalURI());

    context.getOutputStream()
      .write(("Message added in the writer interceptor in the client side").getBytes());

    context.proceed();
}
```